# About normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working on a problem regarding the spectrum of a normal operator and get stuck here.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A\in L(H)$ is normal, if we know $\mathrm{Re}\left<x,Ax\right><0$ for some $x\in H$, can we say $\mathrm{Re}\left<e^{-tA}y,Ae^{-tA}y\right><0$ for some $y\in H$? I know that $e^{-tA}$ is again normal and commute with $A$, so $\mathrm{Re}\left<e^{-tA}y,Ae^{-tA}y\right>=\mathrm{Re}\left<e^{-tA}y,e^{-tA}Ay\right>$ but it doesn't seem to help determine the sign.

The original problem is to prove that $\mathrm{Re}\lambda>0,\forall\lambda\in \sigma(A)\iff\mathrm{Re}\left<x,Ax\right>>0,\forall x\in H$
and I am proving $\mathrm{Re}\lambda>0,\forall\lambda\in \sigma(A)\Longrightarrow\mathrm{Re}\left<x,Ax\right>>0,\forall x\in H$. The problem gives a hint to prove first $\|e^{-tA}\|\le1,\forall t\ge0$ if $\mathrm{Re}\lambda>0$ for all $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$. I proved it by using $\sigma(e^{-tA})=\{e^\mu|\mu\in\sigma(-tA)\}$ and the fact $\|e^{-tA}\|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(e^{-tA})}|\lambda|$. Then it hints to differentiate the function $t\to\|e^{-tA}x\|^2$. I think if I can find $\frac{d}{dt}\|e^{-tA}x\|^2>0$ independent of $t$, then $\|e^{-tA}x\|^2$ would increse over time and contradicts $\|e^{-tA}\|\le1$. That's where I get stuck. Possibly I am working on a totally wrong direciton.

Answer (score 0):

Why not choose $y=e^{tA}x$? Then $\mathrm{Re}\left<e^{-tA}y,Ae^{-tA}y\right>=\mathrm{Re}\left<x,Ax\right><0$.

Comment: I thought about that, but if we choose $y=e^{tA}x$, then $\frac{d}{dt}\|e^{-tA}y\|^2$ would somehow be zero since it's differentiating a constant, while $\frac{d}{dt}\|e^{-tA}y\|^2=-2\mathrm{Re}\left<x,Ax\right>>0$. What's wrong with this substitution?